# Is there a problem splicing 4awg onto 2ser to attach to a breaker?

Tags: electrical

We are installing a subpanel in our second floor. Normal stuff - a total of 7 light and outlet circuits.   80' from the main panel.  I got a deal on some 2-2-2-4 AL SER and was thinking I'd use a 60amp breaker.  What I didn't know is that #2 doesn't fit into breakers.  Someone suggested splicing a piece of #4 onto the #2 because the breaker will accept size 4.  The main panel was upgraded to 200 amps. It's a Siemens. That's all I know. The subpanel is a Siemens 125 amp 8 space E0816ML1125S. The wire has HXXW-2 in it. We went with this subpanel because it will fit between our old house studs that are 14" on center.

I was thinking that the smaller gauge wire would easily be more wire than we need but that wouldn't be a problem. Does having a larger breaker pose a problem when it's just some lights, a few clock radios, and maybe a window AC unit?

Questions - if this makes sense, how long of a piece of #4 do I use?  2" or so?  And are there any issues with dropping size like that?  It just seems odd that I can run one size wire for 79'10" and then change size for 2" and not have a problem.

Update - I edited (added my comments) to my question above for future clarity.  Thanks to everyone for the answers - super helpful.  I was thinking a 60amp breaker was needed because that's what the entire web/ dealer world said would be good to use - or, go all the way to 100amps.  Would be good to know how the decision to use 60amps became the norm.  I ended up buying a Siemens 70amp breaker since that takes #2.  The Eaton 60amp breakers take #2 but there was confusion about whether they actually are ok to use in a Siemens box (the Eaton packaging does not list Siemens) but there are electrical dealers who says it's ok.  All the best.

Comment: [Edit] to provide details about your panels, preferably including pictures of the panels and their labels, for more specific advice on "other things that might work here" and/or "take that back and return it and go buy one like this" advice you can take or ignore, depending what you've got. Cooosing to make sub-panels too small is an "expensive, later" option, normally.

Comment: Voltage drop is proportional to resistance, which is proportional to wire length. The extra resistance from 6” of #4 vs #2 on an 80’ run is basically zero.

Comment: the main panel was upgraded to 200 amps.  It's a Siemens.  That's all I know.  The subpanel is a Siemens 125 amp 8 space.  E0816ML1125S.  The wire has HXXW-2 on it.  We went with this subpanel because it will fit between our old house studs that are 14" on center.

Comment: I was thinking that the smaller gauge wire would easily be more wire than we need but that wouldn't be a problem.  Does having a 90amp breaker pose a problem when it's just some lights, a few clock radios, and maybe a window AC unit?

Comment: The circuits are protected by the 15a and 20a breakers. Whether the panel is fed by 50a or 60a or 90a or 200a doesn't matter.

Answer (score 7):

> I got a deal on some 2-2-2-4 AL SER and was thinking I'd use a 60amp breaker. What I didn't know is that #2 doesn't fit into breakers.

2-2-2-4 should fit on a ***60A*** breaker...

Almost all the manufacturers have two frame sizes for breakers, the 10-50A breakers use the "small" frame size that goes up to about #6, and the 60-100A breakers use a larger frame size that goes up to at least #1.

If your manufacturer's 60A won't fit, then try a 70A, 80A or 90A breaker.  One of those will take #2, *and you're certainly entitled to use the larger breaker*.

With 90A wire to a "70A bus rating"  subpanel, you're allowed to use 60A or 70A.  But 70A panels are *very* small and I doubt you could get 7 circuits into one.

I suspect you have a 100A or 125A bus rating panel, so you're all set for 60-90A.

There is no such thing as a 60A subpanel.  It's an urban legend. Look at your panel labeling for its actual rating.

> Someone suggested splicing a piece of #4 onto the #2 because the breaker will accept size 4.

*cringe* you'd go broke doing that. Those couplers are like $20 each and the copper #4 won't be cheap either.

Far cheaper to just go to a 70A, 80A or 90A breaker.

Answer (score 6):

So long as the breaker is sized correctly to protect the smallest wire connected to it, you can splice that to any larger size at any point you find convenient. Since 4AWG is allowable on a 60A breaker (by rounding up in the unlikely case that you're using 60°C aluminum wire) - in all other cases it's listed for more than 60A - that is fine. **In point of fact**, the [specs for a Siemens Q 60A dual-pole breaker here](https://www.grainger.com/product/SIEMENS-Miniature-Circuit-Breaker-3CNJ2) state that it will take 2AWG. Still not sure if that fits your panel, but it's a breaker for a panel of the brand you admit to.

2" is **likely** to be inconveniently short to manage the splice and connecting to the breaker, physically. The part of code you'd be toying with there would be that requiring the job to be done in a workmanlike manner. There's no specified minimum length, but you may want more to permit the job to be done without being a kludge.

However the simpler solution (depending on various details we don't know yet) might be to upgrade the ampere size of the breaker and subpanel, since 2-2-2-4 is 90A wire in the normal case that it's connected to 75°C terminals, and it's more convenient to use a breaker it will slot right into. And larger (ampere size) breakers will accept larger wires. Not knowing your particular type of panel, some random 70A breakers do, as expected, take up to 2AWG, as will 80 or 90A breakers. You can feed those to a subpanel of the same **or larger** ampacity (so a 100A or 200A subpanel is just fine, and comes with spaces you'll want to have, someday, if not today.)

Upgrading the breaker size will *probably* cost you less than the connectors you'll need to splice the wire.

Answer (score 4):

Ecnerwal covered the source side pretty well. One important note on the *destination* - i.e., the subpanel. You should really consider a *main panel* as your subpanel. I don't know if a disconnect is absolutely required, but it can certainly be useful when working on the panel, and the easiest way to get that is a main breaker. The best part is that you can easily get a main panel that includes a 100A main breaker, plenty of spaces and (usually) a few "bonus breakers" for < $ 100. So don't go too cheap on the subpanel - by the time you deal with wire splicing (you can't use ordinary cheap little wire nuts to splice big wires) and other issues you haven't saved much, if anything at all.

Comment: I do not understand how your answer has anything to do with the question (-1)

Comment: It is relevant because if the subpanel either (a) uses a small backfed breaker as a disconnect then the same problem applies and this is a solution; (b) small but real possibility that a small (e.g., 12 space) subpanel might not have large enough lugs for 2 AWG. Not sure about the second possibility, but I am suggesting a guaranteed workable and likely very cost-effective solution.